# AdWords Script With Divergent Data from Webview

Tags: google-ads-api

I have the following code on an AdWords script:

```
var campanha = 'xyz';

function main() {

 campanhas = AdWordsApp.campaigns().withCondition("CampaignName = '" + campanha + "'").withCondition('Status = ENABLED').get();
 while(campanhas.hasNext()) {
    campanha = campanhas.next();
    if(campanha.getBiddingStrategyType() != 'ENHANCED_CPC') {
        Logger.log('Ajuste de lance da campanha inválido: ' +campanha.getBiddingStrategyType());
        continue;
    }

    palavras = campanha.keywords().withCondition('Status = ENABLED').forDateRange("YESTERDAY").get();
    while(palavras.hasNext()) {
        palavra = palavras.next();
        estatisticas = palavra.getStatsFor('YESTERDAY');
        lances = palavra.bidding();
        estimativa_primeira = Math.max(palavra.getTopOfPageCpc(), palavra.getFirstPageCpc());

        posicao = estatisticas.getAveragePosition();
        if (posicao > 1) {
            Logger.log(palavra.getText() +" = " +" "+palavra.getTopOfPageCpc()+" "+palavra.getFirstPageCpc());
        }

        //Logger.log(palavra.getText() + ' = '+lances.getCpc()+" = "+estatisticas.getAveragePosition());
    }
}
```

I expected to retrieve the estimated first page CPC and estimated first position CPC. But the values that I received are diferente from the AdWords webinterface. For exemple, for a given keyword the script returned +xxx +yyyy =  0.12 0.05, when I look those keywords on webinterface I have the following values for 0.12 for estimated first page CPC and 0.41 for estimated first position CPC.

Comment: Are you using the correct date range in the webinterface?

Comment: Hi @Casper, on both (script and webinterface) I'm considering the date range Yesterday.

Comment: Can't say I'm able to spot any mistakes in your code. You might want to post this on the [adwords script group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/adwords-scripts). Some people working @ Google answer questions over there.

Comment: Hi @Casper I already did on [Google Advertiser Community](https://www.en.advertisercommunity.com/t5/Advanced-Features/AdWords-Script-With-Divergent-Data-from-Webview/m-p/1110532)

Comment: I'd still suggest to post in the Google Group since the adwords script team will help you out. Unless there is some sort of bug, you'll probably have a solution in 2 days.